# How to assign object records to particular user/profiles?

Tags: apex, custom-object, sharing, standard-objects, governorlimits

How to assign object records to particular user/profiles?
I want to assign object records to particular user or profiles, is it possible? can you share me the logic.

Answer (score 0):

you can assign records to user by means of `OwnerId` field. All custom objects and major part of standard have `OwnerId` field. To assign record to user, put user id as value of `OwnerId`